# Here API Places Photos

Tags: here-api

I have tried both Flutter Here Explore SDK and Rest API to fetch Places Photos from countries like Canada, USA and India but for all these the requests from both SDK and API are returning empty results I.e., zero count for a Place’s WebImage List. Example, if I retrieve Places Detail of Chipotle restaurant in Las Vegas through Flutter Explore SDK, I am able to access Chipotle’s title, address and details attribute but Chipotle’s images list are empty.

Does Here support places’s photos data like Google Places API or TomTom API. I see Here API has this images list field in Places Details section but it does not contain any data for any place In US, Canada or India.

Please advise and let me know if Here supports and provide Places photos and if so for which countries?

Comment: Can you share your rest API for places ?

Comment: Below are 2 basic requests url I tried. I could not find documentation in HERE site for the requests URL that you are using. Could you please direct me to the location, where I can access other methods, req parameter, and response parameter details for the API URL you provided? 

    Yours - https://places.cit.api.here.com/places/v1/discover/search 

    Mine - https://autocomplete.geocoder.ls.hereapi.com/6.2/suggest.json
   
    Mine - https://places.ls.hereapi.com/places/v1/discover/search

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue is with my app_id and app_code where this is a demo id/code picked from https://places.cit.api.here.com/places/# and the URL I used is https://places.cit.api.here.com/places/v1/discover/search?app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&at=36.047,-115.235&q=Chipotle&callback=placesresponse which returns 0 results for images but If I use the same URL with your app_id and app_code, it returns images like a charm. How to get new app_id and app_code as this domain https://places.cit.api.here.com is no longer providing new app_id/app_code but only appid and apikey. The apikey is not accepted in https://places.cit.api.here.com. Please advise.